# How to handle a System.CannotUnloadAppDomainException?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have a custom control with a `ReportViewer` control from Microsoft on it. When the form is active with this custom control, and I exit the application by clicking the red cross (in the top-right corner) I get a `System.CannotUnloadAppDomainException`.

I've read that this is a known bug of the MS ReportViewer control. To prevent this exception from showing, you need to call the `ReleaseSandboxAppDomain` method. I have tried this, but it can't get it to work. I call this method on the `ParentForm_Closing` event in the custom control. But this event is not triggered when you close the application by clicking the red cross in top-right corner.

So my question is, how can I prevent this exception from showing?

Here is the code that calls the `ReleaseSandboxAppDomain` method:

```
this.ParentForm.FormClosing += delegate
{
   reportViewer.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();
};
```

Comment: Could you please show the relevant code (the one that calls `ReleaseSandboxAppDomain`...etc.)?

Comment: The code you posted is fine and should work. If the event is not fired, then there's something else in your code that prevents it. Is there anything special is the Closing event handler of your form?

Comment: I've checked some things and we do handle some stuff when the application is exiting. However, the `FormClosing` event does not fire. Maybe it is because this form (the `ParentForm`) is used in a `Panel`. We have a Framework which loads forms in a `Panel`. The form that is loaded in a panel, contains the user control with the reportviewer.

Comment: You can do the following test: add a breakpoint in the `Closing` event of your form, and see what is the value of `this.[myUserControl].ParentForm`. Btw, what do you mean by "the form is used in a panel"?

Comment: @ken2k I cannot try your suggestion, because the closing form is different than the form which contains the user control. What I mean with "the form is used in a panel" is that we add a form to the `Control` collection of a panel: `var form = new MyForm(); /*do some stuff to make it possible to show a form in a panel*/ myPanel.Controls.Add(form);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact your `ParentForm` is inside a panel definitely **is** your problem.

If I understand your case, you have the following controls/forms:

- `MainForm` is the main form of your application
- `Panel1` is a panel that is a control inside `MainForm`
- `TheParentForm` is a form that is inside `Panel1` (with `TopLevel` as false)
- `UserControl1` is a usercontrol inside `TheParentForm`
- `ReportViewer` is the Microsoft usercontrol inside `UserControl1`

When you close `MainForm`, `TheParentForm` is not closed *because it is not a toplevel form*.
What you could do is add the following code in your `MainForm`n in the `FormClosing` event handler:

```
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Panel1.Controls)
    {
        Form ctrlAsForm = ctrl as Form;
        if (ctrlAsForm != null)
        {
            ctrlAsForm.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This will loop through all controls inside `Panel1`, and try to call the `Close()` method explicitly if the control is a form.
Thus, closing the main form will also close the non-toplevel forms that are inside `Panel1`.

Now, as you already wrote in `UserControl1`:

```
this.ParentForm.FormClosing += delegate
{
   reportViewer.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();
};
```

it should be OK; when `TheParentForm` will be closed, you'll be able to do your clean-up and avoid your exception.